# MySQL - Different encryption for different clients?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

In my scenario, all the client's MySQL data resides in the Service provider's server. How can I let the clients choose their own encryption so that the data still resides in the service provider's server but the service provider cant read the data ?

Comment: You could encrypt the data before storing it in MySql.  Can you explain in greater depth this scenario?

Comment: Let's say, I run a social networking site, where I store all my client's data in a MySQL Server. I have used the default security options available in MySQL for all the customers. I could still decrypt the data and read it. Customers are worried about this. If the client are allowed to use their own keys to encrypt data, then customers would be more satisfied. How can I achieve this ? I have read about BYOE (Bring your own encryption), How could I do this in MySQL ?

Comment: Are you the service provider?

Comment: You can protect yourself against the service provider, with a single key, but you don't need per-client keys for that, and it wouldn't offer any additional security. Your application will still have all the keys available. The key point is your application's ability to keep separate clients separate.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Yes, I am the Service provider. I just want to assure my customer that their data is safe with me, as the key to access the data is with customer. Also whenever NSA is gonna ask for the customers data, I can reply "I have only the encrypted data, The key is with customer".  Is that something logical or people do it in different way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, your users will have to trust you simply because the pages and code in the pages they run originate from you as well. You can try and protect them against any mishap, except your own. Technically speaking that is, you can always have yourself audited of course.